# Bootstrap table server side pagination

Tags: pagination, bootstrap-table

I'm using a Bootstrap table to show users data.  Currently it's using client side pagination but I want to use server-side pagination as my record is very huge.  It would be highly appreciated if anyone can help me out in it.

```
 <table id="tblsers" data-height="400" style="width: 100%;margin-top:0 !important" class="bTable" data-search="true"></table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        getUsers();
    });
    function getUsers() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Data.aspx/getUsers",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            debugger
            var table = "";

            var $tblRegisteredUsersTbl = $('#tblRegisteredUsers');

            if (response == "none") {

                $tblRegisteredUsersTbl.bootstrapTable('destroy');
                table = "<tr style='font-weight: bold'><td>No records</td></tr>"
                $("#tblRegisteredUsers").html(table);
                $("#tblRegisteredUsers").children("tbody").css("text-align", 'center');
                $("#tblRegisteredUsers").addClass("table table-hover");

            } else {


                $("#tblRegisteredUsers").children("tbody").css("text-align", 'left');
                var registeredUsers = JSON.parse(response.d);
                $($tblRegisteredUsersTbl).hide();
                $tblRegisteredUsersTbl.bootstrapTable('destroy');
                $tblRegisteredUsersTbl.bootstrapTable({
                    method: 'get',
                    columns: [
                    {
                        field: 'SNo', title: 'S.No', width: 10, align: 'center', sortable: true, formatter: function (value, row, index) {
                            if (value == null || value == "") {
                                return ['<span>N/A</span>']
                            }
                            return ['<span>' + value
                                + '</span>'];
                        }
                    },

                              {
                                  field: 'Name', title: 'User Name', align: 'center', sortable: true, width: 100, formatter: function (value, row, index) {

                                      if (value == null || value == "") {
                                          return ['<span>N/A</span>']
                                      }
                                      else {
                                          return value;
                                      }

                                  }
                              },
                              {
                                  field: 'Address', title: 'User Address', align: 'center', sortable: true, width: 100, formatter: function (value, row, index) {

                                      if (value == null || value == "") {
                                          return ['<span>N/A</span>']
                                      }
                                      else {
                                          return value;
                                      }

                                  }
                              },

                            {
                                field: 'Phone', title: 'User Phone', align: 'center', width: 200, sortable: true, formatter: function (value, row, index) {

                                    if (value == null || value == "") {
                                        return ['<span>N/A</span>']
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        return value;
                                    }

                                }
                            },


                    ],
                    onSort: function (name, order) {

                    },
                    data: registeredUsers,
                    cache: false,
                    height: 400,
                    pagination: true,
                    pageSize: 10,
                    pageList: [10, 25, 50, 100, 200],
                    search: true,
                    showColumns: true,
                    showRefresh: true,
                    minimumCountColumns: 2,



                });
                $($tblRegisteredUsersTbl).fadeIn();
              }

        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            showMessage("error", 'Some error occurred\n Please try again !');
        }
    });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please update this thread, either accepting an answer or providing detail via comment or edit why it doesnt answer your issue

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE (2019/05/07)**

@tw1742 asked if 'total' index has to be called that

Answer is no, you can override that with https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#totalfield

> **Attribute:** data-total-field
>
> **Type:** String
>
> **Detail:** Key in incoming json containing 'total' data.
>
> **Default:** 'total'
>
> **Example:** https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#options/total-data-field.html

**Original Answer**

http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#table-options

http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html#options/server-side-pagination.html

There is documentation of features and several good examples, as well as many people asking much more defined questions in the projects github issues

Cant give you a concise answer because all the code is there, but as described in the doco, your format needs to be like this:

```
{
    "total": 200,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Item 0",
            "price": "$0"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Item 1",
            "price": "$1"
        },
```

So the server has to return that, and it can use the param being sent to return the needed subset.

A great example is: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html

You can see there `data?order=asc&limit=10&offset=20` is being set if you select page 2, just hit F12 and keep eye on network panel to see what happens.

Those param are pretty easily transposed into a sql or similar database query, or even just used with whatever server language (php,ect) to return subset of whatever datasource your using.

Example:

```
SELECT column FROM table
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Comment: Does the attribute with the number of rows need to be named "total"?

Comment: @tw1742 - you can override that with https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#totalfield (**Attribute:** data-total-field

**Type:** String

**Detail:**

Key in incoming json containing 'total' data.

**Default:** 'total'

**Example:** https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#options/total-data-field.html)

Comment: This is not showing anything for me, it just stays blank even after checking that my url is returning the correct format

Answer (score 7):

This SCREAMS for [Datatables](http://www.Datatables.net).  It has built-in ajax for doing the query updates you're looking for, plus it has built-in sorting, filtering, paging, etc.

[Here's a simple example](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) of an ajax sourced Datatable.
[You'll also want to look at the styling guide](https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap) to utilize the Bootstrap CSS.

Finally, regardless of whether or not you use datatables, note that you'll have to accomodate for all the various filters, sorting, etc on your server-side -- that is, the query will have to be able to handle any parameters you want to use to cull your data.  The Datatables example has a ready-made example done in PHP, but it's certainly able to talk to any page that returns a JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap table can read data from an url exposing a json array of data.

when you use server side pagination it expects a total field and a row array for results (you can customized those names) but that's counter intuitive as you return all results.

That total turns obvious when you set `data-query-params-type="limit"` https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#queryparamstype then your url will get those params (offset, limit) so you can filter the result.

you can check the example here https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#options/query-params-type.html, and modify pagination to see how your url is queried.

See you can extend those params using https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#queryparams if you need to customize further the url params to pass to server

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap pagination will send a get request to your server
{Offset:10, limit:10}